Standardizing the Equation of the Normal Distribution Curve
For context, I am a new educator teaching statistics.
The equation of any normal distribution curve with mean $\mu$, variance $\sigma^2$, and standard deviation $\sigma$ is
$$y=\frac{e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\hspace{1cm} \text{Call this equation 1}$$
The equation of the standard normal distribution curve is
$$y=\frac{e^{\frac{-z^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\hspace{1cm} \text{Call this equation 2}$$
While knowing these equations is not necessary for solving any problems in class, I felt it would be nice to show that the standardization process that we do "using the z-score" is the direct link between going from the first equation to the second. At first I thought it was merely a substitution, as it is clear that in the exponent of e in equation 1 is $z^2$. But, my confusion arose from trying to reason where that $\sigma$ in the denominator (next to the $\sqrt{2\pi}$) goes. I know that for SND the mean is 0 and the standard deviation is 1, but if we're starting from our normally distributed data, the standard deviation need not be 1, so I don't think its as simple as "we're setting $\sigma=1$" either.
Am I overlooking or misunderstanding the connection between these two equations?

These are probability distribution functions (pdf's), and they make the most sense when they are integrated over an internal. Are you familiar with the "u-substitution" method for dealing with integrals?

@JonathanZ Yeah I am familiar with that and recognize that when using these we are primarily concerned with the area underneath the curve. However, I wanted a way to explain to my students (who do not know integrals or calculus) the connection between the equations for these curves if there is such a thing at their level.

Assuming that the students will only have trouble to understand the matter with $\sigma$ I would plot the function with a wrong normalization in the denominator of $\sqrt{2\pi},.$ Even for someone who does not know how to integrate it should become visually clear that the area under the curve is way too large when $\sigma$ is very large.

You can explain to them like this:
Let's say X~N(0,1), Y= X.
Then Prob(y-ε < Y < y+ε) = Prob(y-ε < X < y+ε) = Prob((y-ε)/ < X < (y+ε)/)
Let's say the pdf of Y is f(y). Then Prob(y-ε < Y < y+ε) = f(y) * 2ε
And pdf of X is g(x), then Prob((y-ε)/ < X < (y+ε)/) = g(y/)/ * 2ε
So f(y) = g(y/)/.
Note that g(x) is your equation 2, g(y/)/ is your equation 1.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

@JoséCarlosSantos Noted. Thanks!

If your students aren't going to follow any explanation involving integrals, I'd try an analogy with area. I like to think of a pdf as a pile of dirt. (Well, a pile of dirt sandwiched between two parallel plates of glass - a normal pile of dirt in your garden would correspond to a pdf in two variables, $p(x,y)$, and it's easier to restrict your dirt pile to lie along a line than to explain the mechanics of higher dimensional probability.) This makes the profile of your pile of dirt correspond to the graph of your pdf.
Anyways, the thicker the pile at any given value, the more likely the value is to happen. And the fact the $p((-\infty, +\infty)) =1$ corresponds to the fact that we always only have 1 sq. ft. of dirt. We can push it around to make different distributions, pile it up here or thin it out there, but we don't add or take away from it.
With that analogy in place, let's talk about normal distributions, and what changing $\sigma$ does. (Changing $\mu$ clearly just changes where the pile is centered. We might as well assume $\mu = 0$, to keep our formulas easier.) And let's discuss the specific case of changing $\sigma = 1$ to $\sigma = 1/4$. You might have to plot a few points of each graph (like @KurtG suggests), but the general effect is to reduce the spread, to push the dirt more closely near the center. And what happens when you do that? Why, the dirt piles up higher near the center! And if we look at the equation, having a $\sigma$ with a value of 1/4 in the denominator, below the exponential, stretches your graph up by a factor of 4. This is the mathematical reflection of the dirt piling up. Conversely, making $\sigma$ larger than one spreads it out more, so it gets thinner, and in this case the $1/\sigma$ factor is less than $1$.
(When students know how to do integrals, this is the point where you could show that if $z = (x-\mu)/\sigma$ then $dz = dx/\sigma$, so you need the $\sigma$ in the denominator to make the overall integral still equal to $1$.)
Setting this all up might be more work than it's worth for you in your class, but I think having the "pdf" $\iff$ "way the dirt is piled up" analogy is a useful one to have in general.
